# UITableViewCell auto layout constraint problems due to separator line height

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have this rather simple UITableViewCell.

[image]

It has an `Avatar` view, the height of which is set to 34 points, with 10 points vertical spacing to the top and the bottom of the cell's `contentView`. The cell itself is set to use an automatic row height, and here I can already see a small problem: the row height value is set to 54.5.

[image]

And yea, when I inspect the `Avatar` view, it has a height of 34.5 even though it has a required constraint to be 34 points tall, and content hugging and compression resistance all set to 1000.

[image]

When I run the app on the iPhone 11 Pro simulator, I get the following warning in the console:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000030a39d0 Jetfly.Avatar:0x7fabbb8e1310.height == 34   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000030a3f70 V:|-(10)-[Jetfly.Avatar:0x7fabbb8e1310]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fabbb8e1ab0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003088d20 Jetfly.Avatar:0x7fabbb8e1310.centerY == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fabbb8e1ab0.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003089ea0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fabbb8e1ab0.height == 54.3333   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000030a39d0 Jetfly.Avatar:0x7fabbb8e1310.height == 34   (active)>
```

And when I inspect my view hierarchy, I can see that the `Avatar` got a height of `34,33` points.

Okay, so it has obviously something to do with the separator line, which is 0.33 points on the 11 Pro (it's an @3x device, making it one pixel). I get that. But.. how do I add constraints that don't cause these warnings and more importantly, don't change the height of my `Avatar` view?

Comment: Content hugging and compression should _never_ be 1000. Put them back at their default values (750 and 250, I believe). You are going to conflict with your height, for one thing.

Comment: They were at their defaults initially and that's when I noticed the problems at first. So that's definitely not the cause - and also it's just not true that they should *never* be at 1000.

Comment: Well, you say what you say and I say what I say on that one.

Comment: FYI I did put them back at their defaults since putting them at 1000 didn't fix anything. It also didn't make it worse, and also didn't get in the way of the real fix (setting one of the vertical spacing constraints to 999). So I am curious why you say they are going to conflict with the height? Can you point to an article or docs that explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower the priority of one vertical-axis constraint to 999. I usually use the bottom constraint from the bottom-most view to the bottom of the content view.