# Using UITableViewDiffableDatasource in UITableView, Add or DeleteCell -> Warning Cell Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewdiffabledatasource

When Cell initializer called function

```
    private func configureUI() {
        [dateLabel, previewLabel].forEach {
            contentsStackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
        }
        
        [titleLabel, contentsStackView].forEach {
            mainStackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
        }
        
        contentView.addSubview(mainStackView)
    }
    
    private func setUpConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            mainStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
        ])
        
        dateLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        previewLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(1), for: .horizontal)
    }
    
    private func setUpAccessory() {
        accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    }
```

Add or Delete Cell Warning Log Message

```
2023-09-05 19:52:06.961611+0900 Diary[7318:185913] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000118050 V:|-(5)-[UIStackView:0x13c70e940]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x13c71acd0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001180a0 UIStackView:0x13c70e940.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x13c71acd0.bottom - 5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000011f9d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x13c71acd0.height == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001180a0 UIStackView:0x13c70e940.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x13c71acd0.bottom - 5   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

When you swipe the TableViewCell, the above Log Warning occurs, and when you Delete and scroll the screen, it appears to be a warning that occurs as the Cell is reused.

Since there is no warning when the TableView is first exposed, I don't think it is a problem with the constraints inside the cell. I'm confused because the Warning Message is listed as a problem related to Constraints.

Answering Forward Questions

Comment: The last warning effectively says that autolayout thinks the stuff inside cell has a height of zero. Figure that out.

Comment: Your UISTackView bottom constrinat is breaking. it is coming UITableViewCellContentView. bottom-5 make it positive . It's not getting required height.Fix the bottom constraint then warning should not come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete

```
mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
```

Instead, create this constraint, assign it a priority of 999, and then activate it.

So, your code will say:

```
private func setUpConstraints() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mainStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        mainStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
    ])
    let bottomConstraint = mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
    bottomConstraint.priority = .init(999)
    bottomConstraint.isActive = true
    dateLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    previewLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(1), for: .horizontal)
}
```

Comment: hello. I applied your answer to my project and confirmed that Warning is no longer output.

What caused this and why is it a problem that can be solved by lowering the priority?

Comment: `'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' is the runtime applying an initial estimated (some might say arbitrary) height to your cell, offscreen. You must not conflict with that, so you lower one of your vertical constraints. On the next pass, the runtime uses your internal constraints and the cell appears at the right height.

Comment: Until now, while setting constraints for cells, we have often given constraints to each cell to affect the size of the content inside the cell, but a warning like the above has never occurred. Is the example above because the Delete function via Swipe was included? Or is it because it was applied through DiffableDataSource? I am curious about the root cause of this warning.

Comment: I don't know why it only happens sometimes but it happens to me a lot on all kinds of cells and table / collection views. Here's another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599451/341994